# SPAM flag declined but flagged post contains spam link & was deleted by moderator

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

[How to convert List<T> to Array t[] (for primitive types) using generic-method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149412/how-to-convert-listt-to-array-t-for-primitive-types-using-generic-method/25149583#25149583)

The answer I flagged contains nothing but garbage text and links to "bioderma" and "ducray".  Can someone explain why the SPAM flag was declined?  Seems pretty clear to me that the only purpose of the post was to get someone to click the links.

Comment: Yup, that's spam alright. Probably a misclick by the moderator. Mistakes happen.

Comment: OK, that seems reasonable. I just wanted to make sure my interpretation of SPAM wasn't vastly different from the community standards.

Comment: Looks like they just voted to delete (which is binding and instant) rather than handle the flag.  It's possible in fact that the moderator didn't even know about your flag, just happened across the question at the same time.  (If it was deleted from handling the flag, I don't think it would list you as voting to delete it).  It also wasn't deleted 'as spam', or it would show up differently.  (But it should be!)

Comment: @Joe - Upon deletion of the post, spam flags are marked helpful, even if we didn't see them. I'm guessing this was just a matter of clicking the wrong button. They'd spammed this stuff elsewhere, so I went ahead and destroyed their account.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @BradLarson the Destroyer!!!!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yeah, this one was my fault.

Part of the problem is that, if a post gets -3 votes or more and gets dimmed by the "your answer sucks" CSS, the spam links are obscured.  I may file that as a bug.

[image]

In the absence of spam links, it's just gibberish.  Removable with extreme prejudice, but not spam.