# Declined spam flag although post was removed

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam, disputed-flags

There was an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51760041/5366641), saying (as far as I remember) something like:

> sorry for this. just a test.. take care guys.

I have reviewed the answer from the queue and flagged it to my understanding as a spam.

When I checked the result later, it turned out, that the question is indeed removed, but my flag was declined. I am definitely not concerned about my flag count, but to have an idea how to proceed in such cases in the future. So, I have read on the meta, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371693/5366641) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268526/5366641), that there are sometimes mistakes by approving the flags. And my question is - was that a mistake, or I did something wrong?

If it was a mistake - it's not a big deal. However, if I did something wrong, please take your time to explain me (again, to avoid this in the future).

Comment: IIRC testing is R/A. But I don't think there's a big enough difference for a spam flag to be declined and an R/A flag to be approved on the same post

Comment: Technically, if this post is elegible to recieve a red flag, then Rude/Abusive would have been more appropriate (due to abuse of the system/site). However, there isn't much of a difference between R/A and spam flags, and hence spam flags aren't usually declined on R/A posts.

Comment: I have to say, that's not spam. The spam flag states: _"Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation."_ and this is just rubbish, not spam.

Comment: Related: [What is the exact definition of “spam” for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: @angussidney, I now see a misunderstanding from my side about the Rude/Abusive flag: I have considered its meaning based on only the first part of it - Rude. Thank you for pointing out what would have been more appropriate to do in this case!

Comment: see also: [Why don't we treat rubbish the same as spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/165773)

Comment: the flag was [disputed]( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372811/3956566) not declined.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Spam flags are (among) the "loudest" you can raise.
And this answer only qualifies for less of an alarm bell.
It is definitly NAA (not an answer) and worth flagging as such.

I think there are some StackOverflow users who would consider it "abuse" of the StackOverflow mechanisms and the sites idea as a whole; but that flag also is very "loud".

I am with you, in case your reasoning is that StackOverflow should not be "spammed" with non-answers only for testing purposes. But the flag is on a different level and mostly for attempts to draw attention/clicks to something, with questionable motivation.
In sophisticated cases, that does not necessarily require a URL inside the post (I will of course not explain how to sophistically spam...);
but a newbie just trying the features does not deserve that suspicion.
Surely you agree that this post, as inappropriate as it is, obviously does not show anything like that.

Picking up and extending Suraj Raos comment:

> a post marked as spam comes with a heavy penalty for the poster

The penalty for the poster is a very important part of what I called "loud".
Another part of the loudness is the effect on moderators. They tend to "jump" at spam flags, with high priority and tend to drop other (also useful) things they are doing. Also they might actually get some additional stress from spam flags.
Be nice to answereres/askers and moderators. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the level of strength of the flags! I understand the addition you've just made too. However, in general, is it really so important to put exactly the right label to the post (NAA, R/A or Spam), when it is obvious that it should be removed? I don't speak about the difficult cases, but the obvious ones.

Comment: @scopchanov a post marked as spam comes with a heavy penalty for the poster... We generally use Hanlon's Razor before using it

Comment: @scopchanov Besides what Suraj Roa just mentioned, they can be handled differently too. NAA flags end up on the Low Quality Posts review queue and are handled by the community, while spam/rude or abusive flags can only be handled by moderators.

Comment: @Ivar, thank you for shading light on the inner workings, as well as for the info, provided in your previous comment! Thank definitely helps me to understand better the rules and how to apply them.

Comment: @SurajRao What is Hanlon's Razor? (And I picked up your comment for a more complete answer - assuming that you don't mind.)

Comment: @Yunnosch, that really improves my understanding of how it is intended to work. Thank you for your time and the explanations!

Comment: @Yunnosch [Never attribute to malice which is explained by stupidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor)

Comment: By a few seconds you beat my in finding it. Thanks.

Comment: However assuming somebody (especially adversaries) being stupid is very dangerous. I learned that it is safer to assume carelessnes, egoistic behaviour or laziness. No poster on StackOverflow is of course your or my adversary, but carelessness (about the rules and how the behaviour affects others) or lazy/egoistic behaviour (deleting it needs several additional clicks) is a slightly kinder interpretation than stupidity. @SurajRao

Comment: @Yunnosch: I think that's a flaw of the (original? Most common?) wording of Hanlon's razor more than anything else.

Comment: Considering the main point here, I have also been in this situation that I flagged something and before anyone reviews that,the post got removed and my flag got declined

Comment: Most of my declined flags are either of removed posts or posts edited after flagged

Comment: @VivekMishra Interesting. My experiences with flagging posts which got edited afterwards would support the assumption that moderators judge helpfulness of flags based on the state of the flagged post at the time of flagging. I always got the impression that judgements of my declined/helpful flags match the post-version I had flagged. Do you think that could apply to your posts, too? I mean, could you see the judgement also applying to the version you flagged and not only to the edited version? In case you think that impossible I am with you and would appreciate a diamonds comment on this.

Comment: I flagged an answer as not an answer as it was not related at all and was just one line. But my flag was declined and when I checked the answer again, the answerer has added 5000 characters

Comment: @VivekMishra That might be worth a separate meta question (after some due duplicate search).

Comment: But I am not sure about real reason as many of posts are removed too. My main declined flags are from Very Low quality as I misunderstood it in earlier days.

Answer (score 12):

I disputed the flag (not declined it) and then deleted the post.

It wasn't spam. It wasn't rude or abusive - the user had no other history to suggest a troll. If a post is rude or abusive and has a spam flag on it (or vice versa), I will mark it as helpful as both flags cause the account to have an instant IP ban.

However, it wasn't an answer. So it was deleted.

A Not an answer flag would have worked well in this case.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Like the spam flag reason says: "Exists only to promote a product or service". Unless the post is doing that, it is not spam.

A post just saying "sorry for this. just a test.. take care guys." and literally nothing else, isn't spam, it isn't rude/abusive, but *very low quality*: it contains nothing of value and can't be salvaged. It is also *not an answer*.

The post should not be flagged as spam, but simply deleted. Flag as "very low quality" or "not an answer".

If you get something like this as part of the low quality post review, and the contents are just completely random, simply pick "Delete" -> "no comment needed".